# Proper use of withMemoryRebound

Tags: swift

I am using the following code:

```
audioBuff.audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0].withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: bufferSizePOT / 2) {dspComplexStream in
        vDSP_ctoz(dspComplexStream, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
    }
```

I'd like to jump to some further samples doing this:

```
audioBuff.audioBuffer.floatChannelData![1024].withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: bufferSizePOT / 2) {dspComplexStream in
        vDSP_ctoz(dspComplexStream, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
    }
```

when doing so, I have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
someone could explain how to use it properly?

I used the .withMemoryRebound because i initialy tried:

```
vDSP_ctoz(audioBuff.audioBuffer.floatChannelData!, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
```

which gave me the error:
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer'

what I would like to do is to move into the audioBuff.audioBuffer.floatChannelData! by chunks to do FFTs

Comment: Isn't that error the nil unwrapping error? Corroborated with the forced unwrap might explain the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]` represents a pointer to samples of channel#0.

You can access samples of channel#1 with `audioBuffer.floatChannelData![1]` when the buffer is non-interleved stereo.

But, I believe any of the Apple's sound hardware does not support channel#1024.

You may need to write something like this when you want to use the samples from the 1024th:

```
    audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]
        .advanced(by: 1024)
        .withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: bufferSizePOT / 2) {
    dspComplexStream in
        vDSP_ctoz(dspComplexStream, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks OOPer for this!